# I R ,how to summarise numeric columns automaticaly. Thanks

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, across

I R ,how to summarise numeric columns automaticaly. Thanks

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(label=LETTERS[1:8],
             x = rep(2:5, each = 2) / 2, 
             y = rep(2:3, each = 4) / 2)


df %>% sum(across(where(is.numeric))) #can't work
df %>% sum(where(is.numeric)) #can't work
```

Comment: `df %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `across` inside a `dplyr` verb, such as `mutate` or `summarize`, then you need to define the function you want to apply in `.fns`, I used *mean* as an example in your data.

```
df %>% summarize(across(.cols = where(is.numeric),.fns = mean))

# A tibble: 1 x 2
      x     y
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  1.75  1.25
```